# Redistribute votes while eliminating candidates

Tags: mysql

Consider this thought. I have a ranking choice voting system, where candidates that doesn't meet the threshold are eliminated during different rounds. In this example we have 6 candidates running for two seats in a primary election. At this point we have reached round 4 (with no winner) where candidates 3 and 5 have already been eliminated. In this round candidate 4 is being eliminated and his/hers votes are about to be redistributed to those candidates marked as second or third choice on each ballot where candidate 4 was marked as first choice.

We grab all ballots where candidate 4 is the first choice (which happens to be 4 ballots). They look like this:

Candidate 4:
4 1 6 3 2 5
4 3 1 6 2 5
4 5 6 2 3 1
4 3 1 5 6 2

The redistributed votes are (in bold):
4 **1** 6 3 2 5
4 3 **1** 6 2 5
4 5 **6** 2 3 1
4 3 **1** 5 6 2

Now for my problem: I need to write a MySQL query that grabs these values and counts the number of votes each given candidate recieves through this redistribution. I.e. the result with the MySQL query should look like this:

Candidate 1: 3 votes
Candidate 6: 1 vote

EDIT: This query need to know that candidates 3 and 5 are already eliminated thus heading for the next column to find any other candidate.

How would I write a MySQL query to get this result?

Comment: How are these values stored? Are they 6 columns on a table, or 6 rows relating to a single row on a main table?

Comment: They are stored as 6 columns in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been having a play.

I think using your current layout of data if could be done as:-

```
SELECT COALESCE(IF(vote_candidate_b IN (4,3,5), NULL, vote_candidate_b),
                IF(vote_candidate_c IN (4,3,5), NULL, vote_candidate_c),
                IF(vote_candidate_d IN (4,3,5), NULL, vote_candidate_d),
                IF(vote_candidate_e IN (4,3,5), NULL, vote_candidate_e),
                IF(vote_candidate_f IN (4,3,5), NULL, vote_candidate_f)) AS vote_candidate,
                COUNT(*)
FROM votes
WHERE vote_candidate_a = 4
GROUP BY vote_candidate;
```

This is pretty much as fancypants has answered. I am not keen on this as it doesn't seem easy to read and (if the amount of data is large) is likely to be inefficient.

I would be more inclined to split the data off into a different table structure, with multiple rows per set of votes, one per candidate. This would be far easier to do if the system is in the early stages of development (ie, you just generate the new tables).

Assuming your existing data was set up as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE votes
(
    vote_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vote_candidate_a INT,
    vote_candidate_b INT,
    vote_candidate_c INT,
    vote_candidate_d INT,
    vote_candidate_e INT,
    vote_candidate_f INT
);

INSERT INTO votes
VALUES
(NULL, 4, 1, 6, 3, 2, 5),
(NULL, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5),
(NULL, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1),
(NULL, 4, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2);
```

my format could be generated as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE vote_orders
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vote_id INT,
    vote_order INT,
    vote_candidate INT
);

INSERT INTO vote_orders (id, vote_id, vote_order, vote_candidate)
SELECT NULL, vote_id, 1, vote_candidate_a FROM votes
UNION
SELECT NULL, vote_id, 2, vote_candidate_b FROM votes
UNION
SELECT NULL, vote_id, 3, vote_candidate_c FROM votes
UNION
SELECT NULL, vote_id, 4, vote_candidate_d FROM votes
UNION
SELECT NULL, vote_id, 5, vote_candidate_e FROM votes
UNION
SELECT NULL, vote_id, 6, vote_candidate_f FROM votes;
```

You could then simply use the following to get the votes. This uses a sub query to get the highest vote that hasn't already been used and then joins that back against the data.

```
SELECT vote_candidate, COUNT(*)
FROM vote_orders a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT vote_id, MIN(vote_order) AS min_vote_order
    FROM vote_orders
    WHERE vote_candidate NOT IN (4,3,5)
    GROUP BY vote_id
) b
ON a.vote_id = b.vote_id
AND a.vote_order = b.min_vote_order
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT vote_id
    FROM vote_orders
    WHERE vote_candidate  = 4
    AND vote_order = 1
) c
ON a.vote_id = c.vote_id
GROUP BY vote_candidate
```

SQL fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d48c/10

A hybrid solution (worst of both worlds!):-

```
SELECT vote_candidate, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
    SELECT vote_id, 1 AS vote_order, vote_candidate_a AS vote_candidate FROM votes WHERE vote_candidate_a = 4
    UNION
    SELECT vote_id, 2, vote_candidate_b FROM votes WHERE vote_candidate_a = 4
    UNION
    SELECT vote_id, 3, vote_candidate_c FROM votes WHERE vote_candidate_a = 4
    UNION
    SELECT vote_id, 4, vote_candidate_d FROM votes WHERE vote_candidate_a = 4
    UNION
    SELECT vote_id, 5, vote_candidate_e FROM votes WHERE vote_candidate_a = 4
    UNION
    SELECT vote_id, 6, vote_candidate_f FROM votes WHERE vote_candidate_a = 4
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT vote_id, MIN(vote_order) AS min_vote_order
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT vote_id, 2 AS vote_order, vote_candidate_b AS vote_candidate FROM votes
        UNION
        SELECT vote_id, 3, vote_candidate_c FROM votes
        UNION
        SELECT vote_id, 4, vote_candidate_d FROM votes
        UNION
        SELECT vote_id, 5, vote_candidate_e FROM votes
        UNION
        SELECT vote_id, 6, vote_candidate_f FROM votes
    ) a
    WHERE vote_candidate NOT IN (4,3,5)
    GROUP BY vote_id
) b
ON a.vote_id = b.vote_id
AND a.vote_order = b.min_vote_order
GROUP BY vote_candidate;
```

Comment: Wow - This also is helpful. I must say I'm no expert at MySQL but I do agree that @fancypants solution may turn out inefficient if the table becomes overwhelmingly large (which it might). This solutions seems on the other hand more complex, but I'll have a look at it and give it a try too. I'll mark it as an answer too. :) Thanks alot. I might return with extended questions if I run into any.

Comment: No problem. If you stored your votes originally in a normalised form (ie, something like the format I extract them to) this would be easier. Multiple columns with different names but on the same table holding virtually the same data is always a problem to deal with. For example if you added a 7th possible vote your current solution would require table changes. Storing a vote per line would allow you to avoid any table changes.

Comment: Good point. I will do that. As I dig into your query things get more and more clear to me. :) I'll get back to you since I know I will run into more questions as the newbie I am to this!

Comment: If you had a table of voters as well that could make things easier. So each entry on voters represents one person with a vote, and would have multiple rows on the vote_orders table. You may already have this though.

Comment: At this point I have a piece of paper with a lot of writings on but no actual database nor tables. I'm trying to blueprint the voting system before I add the real tables. That's why I'm jawdropping every time I get a good hint by you on how to proceed. :) I ran into this problem in my mind as I was working on the blueprint. I'll take any good advice with me! :)

Comment: May I add something to this. How about if I want to see even the count of candidates 3 and 6 original votes? How would I add that to the query you've described?

Comment: That would depend on where you require that count, and at what stage. Possible to just do a query to get the original votes for those candidates and UNION the results onto the main results.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that but the problem is that I run into tons of troubles with "unknown column"-errors when I try to union the original votes column onto the main results. You could check out this fiddle [link]http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ab55/177.

Comment: With a union the columns must match between each unioned query.

Comment: The thing is that unioned queries replaces everything in Table 1 with the contents of Table 2 based on the matching columns. But I only want to combine one column (original_votes) from T2 with T1 which is where my headache occurs since I can't find any information on how to combine only one column from one table with one column in another. In my linked fiddle I return errors when I try to add a union between both select queries. How should this be performed?

Comment: The linked SQL fiddle didn't have a union in it. Could you modify the original question (or possibly better, post a new question) including details of the input data (easy) and what you want output with these extra counts.

Comment: I removed the union from the fiddle to avoid the errors. :) I've posted a new question in this matter. You can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244729/combining-one-column-between-two-tables-in-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, if I understood you right?

```
select
coalesce(if(c2 in (3,5), null, c2),
         if(c3 in (3,5), null, c3),
         if(c4 in (3,5), null, c4),
         if(c5 in (3,5), null, c5),
         if(c6 in (3,5), null, c6)) as candidate,
count(*) as votes
from Table1
where c1 = 4
group by candidate
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b8b3/1/0)</kbd>

Explanation:

`coalesce()` returns the first of its parameters which isn't `null`. With the `if()` we say, if column value is 3 or 5 replace it with null. So you get the first column in the order you specify, which is not for the eliminated candidates. Then you just group by it and count the rows.

Comment: Wow - great solution and a solid explanation. :) Thanks a lot!