# Why doesn't the conditional value match the query passed from a MySQL-table?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a tricky question that I can't seem to find any solution too. I've scanned SO for related issues to gain inspiration from but there seems to be no previous answers that solves my issue. This question is a evolvement of these previous questions I've asked in a similar matter - [Combining one column between two tables in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244729/combining-one-column-between-two-tables-in-mysql) and [Redistribute votes while eliminating candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990750/redistribute-votes-while-eliminating-candidates). So here we go...

I've built a voting system in VB.NET and MySQL that transfers votes between candidates based on their ballots second preferred choices (more about how this works can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote)).

I've reached a point where the redistribution of votes works perfectly if there are any preferences to redistribute to. But in cases where all preferenced candidates on a ballot already has been eliminated the ballot must be exhausted and this is where it programmatically becomes troublesome. I have a MySQL query that looks for the next available preference (2 to the number of candidates left in the race) on each ballot of an eliminated candidate. If there are no preferences left the query returns NULL. To avoid this I'm using COALESCE to replace the NULL with 0. I then try to use an If-statement in VB.NET to perform different actions based on the return value (0 = exhausted votes, 1 = eliminated candidate, 2 to x = redistribution on eliminated candidates votes).
For some reason (and this is my issue) the If-statement never runs (hence 0 is never interpreted). It runs into ELSE whatever value being returned.

This is the MySQL-query. Return value '1' is always ignored as it references the current candidate about to be eliminated:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT candidate, COALESCE(MIN(preference), 0) preference FROM (
SELECT 'vote_candidate_1' candidate, vote_candidate_1 preference FROM votes WHERE vote_id = '350' UNION
SELECT 'vote_candidate_2' candidate, vote_candidate_2 preference FROM votes WHERE vote_id = '350' UNION
SELECT 'vote_candidate_3' candidate, vote_candidate_3 preference FROM votes WHERE vote_id = '350' UNION
SELECT 'vote_candidate_4' candidate, vote_candidate_4 preference FROM votes WHERE vote_id = '350' UNION
SELECT 'vote_candidate_5' candidate, vote_candidate_5 preference FROM votes WHERE vote_id = '350')
pivot WHERE preference > '1' ORDER BY preference ASC;
```

Running this query in phpMyAdmin returns exactly what I expect (I'm only interested of the preference column at this stage):

```
+-----------+------------+
| candidate | preference |
+-----------+------------+
|      NULL |          0 |
+-----------+------------+
```

I've examined the union statement using EXPLAIN to understand what's going on in the query. It returns the following:

```
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table            | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | extra                            |
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY      | <derived2>       | ALL   |          NULL | PRIMARY |    NULL |  NULL |    5 | Using where; Using temporary     |
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
| 2  | DERIVED      | votes            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |                                  |
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
| 3  | UNION        | votes            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |                                  |
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
| 4  | UNION        | votes            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |                                  |
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
| 5  | UNION        | votes            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |                                  |
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
| 6  | UNION RESULT | <union2,3,4,5,6> | ALL   |          NULL |    NULL |    NULL |  NULL | NULL |                                  |
+----+--------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------+
```

I figure something might be going on with the type column as it jumps from ALL to const back to ALL. There are several threads about this matter in this Q&A, but I can't find anything that answers the issue I'm facing.

This is the VB.NET If-statement that gives me concerns.

```
Dim preferencedReader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing

preferencedReader = CmGetNextPreferencedCandidates.ExecuteReader()

If preferencedReader.HasRows Then
    While preferencedReader.read()
        If Convert.ToInt32(preferencedReader("preference")) = 0 Then
            ' Exhaust the vote
        Else
            ' Redistribute the vote.
        End If
   End While
```

End If

This If-statement ALWAYS enters the Else-clause. To me it seems as preferencedReader("preference") ALWAYS contains something other than 0 even when the query returns 0. Is there a type mismatch or am I misunderstanding anything else at this point?

Comment: You are declaring the `preferenceReader` object and setting it to Nothing. Are you sure you aren't getting a null reference exception? It'll never have rows because it is `Nothing`.

Comment: When the query returns preference = 2, preferencedReader(“preference”) also returns 2. From that I figure the reader does return things from the table even if it’s declared as ‘Nothing’. But I don’t know what the reader returns when the query = 0 as it always seem to skip that queried return value. In other words - if the query returns anything other than 0 the reader returns everything as expected within the else-statement but nothing in the if-statement if the query returns 0.

Comment: Since it is unclear exactly what is being returned, instead of convert.toint32, use Integer.TryParse which will return False if Null gets through.

Comment: Perhpas you omitted code between the Reader declaration and the check for .HasRows?

Comment: Your right - sorry man, I absolutely did. I didn't see it - thanks for pointing that out. I just edited the code to fill in the missing code. :)

Comment: @dsd7a7 I tried to change to Integer.TryParse and it stopped all actions inside the Else-part of the If-statement. I'm even more confused now...